# Django application to upload videos on S3 using boto3

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto3

I am new to Django and want to develop an application to upload videos on AWS S3 using Boto3.

Please guide me step-by-step on how to implement this?

As I am new it's little hard for me to understand.

Earlier I tried and created one Form with `form.FileField()` and it returns `File Object` but that `fileobject` I am not able to upload using boto3 as `upload_fileObj` method must require read implemented as a `rb`.

Thanks in advance and waiting for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first create a file from your File Object in /tmp/ directory.
After that you can use that file path to upload using [upload_file](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file)

once you are sure that the file is uploaded successfully you can delete that file from /tmp/ directory. 
Incase, file is not being properly uploaded you can retry it also.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. I am getting one error related to header like: `CreatedMultipartupload operation: Missing required header for this request:  x-amz-content-sha256`
Please help me in that. Thanks

Comment: what is config file you had set? , did you mention your region correctly ?
 check https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2138

Comment: Hi Anoop, My config file contains `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` , `AWS_PRIVATE_KEY` ,`region = us-west-2` ( means OREGON) and  `signature_version = s3v4` . I already visited the given link but still facing this issue.

Comment: which boto3 version you are using ? can u share your code?

Comment: are you getting same kind of exception for ListObjects operation also?

Comment: Hi still I am doing with video upload so using `upload_fileobj()` function only.
`boto3 =1.4.4` , `botocore=1.5.52`

Comment: Here it is ...
`import boto3

Comment: Here it is ...
`import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3',region_name='us-west-2',api_version='2006-03-01',aws_access_key_id= **AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID**,aws_secret_access_key=**AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY**)

bucket = s3.Bucket(**BUCKET_NAME**)

obj = bucket.Object(**KEY**)

with open(temp_path,'rb') as data:
        obj.upload_fileobj(data)`

Comment: try this - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1f398bddfbe004892fbcb2ecd4b606d8   , remove api_version

Comment: @MayankAcharya , glad it solves your query .. please upvote my answer if you liked it

Comment: Hi Tom, I already upvoted your answer but my reputation score in low so It won't be shown up. Thank you for help.